# Preload images in jquery/canvas "Uncaught TypeError: Type error"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, preloading

I want to pre-load a directory of images into my canvas so that they are ready to be displayed when I need them.

[I found this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)
and the accepted answer was extremely helpful.
Their function iterates through an array of image locations and then (i presume) pre-loads them to the canvas.

I am having difficulties actually displaying them once they are pre-loaded using this function. I'm well aware of the single image loading method of-

```
img = new Image();
img.src = imgLocation;
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

but since they are already loaded, I am *assuming* I don't need to use `img.onload` or any of the above code except for `context.drawImage` to actually display the image.

When I try to load an image from the (what i can only assume is the out-putted array with all the images in it) i get a **type error**.  when I check what's inside the array ( with a `console.log()` ) at any index it says `[object, Object]`

My code code looks like this:

```
var framesArr = new Array();
var framesAmnt = 300; // we would normally get this number from the PHP side of things

function ldBtn(){

    //load all frames locations into framesArr
    var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=(framesAmnt-1);i++){
        framesArr[i] = "frames/Frame" + i + ".png";
    }

    //preload them
    preloadImages(framesArr, preloadDone);
}

var deferreds = [];
var deferred;

function preloadImages (paths, callback) {

    $.each(paths, function (i, src) {
        deferred = $.Deferred(),
        img = new Image();

        deferreds.push(deferred);
        img.onload = deferred.resolve;
        img.src = src;
    });

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(callback);
}

function preloadDone(){
    //any old index number will do. *Shruggs*
    context.drawImage(deferreds[2], 0, 0); //this will cause a type error.
}
```

How can I display images onto the canvas that were loaded by the `preloadImages` function?

I suppose I don't fully understand what happens when `img = new Image();` `img.src = imgLocation;` `img.onload = function()` happens. What does javascript/jquery store the image as? if the answer is 'an object' then why won't it load the objects in this array?

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to pass an actual image element to the `drawImage` method. Now you're passing a deferred in.

Next, there's a bug with Chrome and native elements constructor (`new Image()`).

So, simply use `document.createElement("img")` which will do exactly the same thing - without the bug.

See the related bugs:

- About Canvas:
  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238071
- The root cause: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245296

I created a reduced example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YVDpD/

Comment: Forgive me for sounding both shocked and brainless, but are you suggesting it's not my fault? XDD   either way, could you please suggest to me where in my code I should change `new Image()` ?  do you mean the one in `preloadImages` ? because that still gave a type error. Additionally, are you saying that my code is sound and should work?(except for the chrome bug) please clarify, I'm a little confused.

Comment: Actually, you had a problem where you where passing a Deferred object to the `drawImage` method instead of an image object. I fixed the answer the take this into account and added a reduced demo based on your core code.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `new Array()` in JavaScript, use the literal form `var framesArr = []`. There's some quirks happening when you use object constructor (that goes for all native type: String, Boolean, Number, Function, etc)

Comment: Thank you immensely for your clarifications, especially your JSfiddle, you fixed it and now I understand why and how it works. additionally, I wasn't aware that using 'new' anything was 'bad practice' and I have appended my code wherever it appears. =D lastly, that picture you used as an example is adorable. Did you draw it? =D   Many thanks again!

Comment: Haha, no, that's a picture from the Octodex: http://octodex.github.com/

Just for clarification, it's not no `new` anything (inheritance is allright really). It's no `new` **native type**. The underlying issue is that these constructors create what we call a _complex object_ and they become unusable by `typeof` - of course there's work around implemented in libraries, but dealing with a complex object is not really nice for your colleagues. E.G.: `typeof new String("hey") === "object"` VS `typeof "hey" === "string"`